# MailApp.sendEmail Google Script Function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("VSDTest");
  
  var speedvsd = e.values[1];
  Logger.log(speed);
  
  if(speedvsd > 500 || speedvsd < 100){
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("speedvsd");
  template.speedvsd = speedvsd;
  //template.recorded = recorded;
  //template.remarks = remarks;
    var email = 'someone@gmail.com';
    var subject = 'Out of Range Notification';
    var msg = 'Speed = '+speedvsd;
    
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msg);
  }
  
}
```

The code above does not get the email through. But with the same code changing `MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msg)` to `MailApp.sendEmail("someone@example.com","Test Subject","Test Message")` that actually works. My main goal is to collect responses from a Google Form. On certain columns, I have applied conditional formatting whereby if some data are above or lower than a certain value, it will trigger and send an email.

The issue here is I am not sure what causes it to not send through. I have created a trigger that will trigger upon form submit.

```js
MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
                    "Out of Range Notification",
                    "",
                    {htmlBody : template.evaluate().getContent()});
```

I have also tried this and it didn't work.

edit: Now it works with the answer below. However, when I try to use `var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(filename)` and in my `MailApp.sendEmail(email,subject,""{htmlbody: template.evaluate().getContent()});` this doesn't send me any email at all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  var speed = e.values[1];
  Logger.log(speed);
  if(speed){
    var email = 'someone@gmail.com';
    var subject = 'Testing‘;
    var msg = 'Speed = '+speed;
    MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, msg);
  }

}
```

Comment: That worked but I don't see a real difference vs what I did on the top. Also, is there a way to use the template command that I used? I have .html files under my script and I have templates in it. Under body I have used ``{htmlBody : template.evaluate().getContent()}`` , the issue came back with the email not going through. @Cooper